# Get dataframe subset by attribute's property in sliced way

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have DataFrame with one of the columns of datetime type (called 'Date'). I can get a subset of my dataframe by full date, like that:

```
df[df['Date'] >= '2013-11-01']
```

However, I want to get a dataframe subset by sertain time interval (ignoring dates). For example, the following code would not work:

```
df[(df['Date'].time() >= datetime.strptime("12:00:00", "%H:%M:%S").time()) &
   (df['Date'].time() <= datetime.strptime("16:00:00", "%H:%M:%S").time())]
```

because of `df['Date'].time()` is not appropriate way to address `time()` method.

Is there any way to do the same without getting to `iterrows`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convert the column to `DatetimeIndex` first, then you can call many methods that deal with datetime, for example:

```
hour = pd.DatetimeIndex(df["Date"]).hour
df[(hour >= 12) & (hour <= 16)]
```